# Is there a way to do bot internationalization in Slack?

Tags: slack-api

I have implemented a custom slash command in Slack. Now I would like it to send different responses depending on user locale. After examining [Slack API documentation](https://api.slack.com/) I could not find any reference to internationalization.

Comment: Yes, I don't think there is much you can do around this at the moment beyond asking the user for their location :/

Answer (score 0):

Slack does not store the user locale, but you can get the timezone info of a user with `users.list`. Since the timezone info usually also includes country and next metro city, you should be able to estimate the user locale.

See [here](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list) for the documentation of that method.

**Update**

Since September 2017 Slack has added an optional locale feature to its API. Check out [this post](https://api.slack.com/changelog/2017-09-locale-locale-locale) for details.